# How to access dev folder in android?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

I'm making android app through Unity, which will access and read data output from serial device, connected through USB cable to tablet. I have everything figured out except one thing.

When I try APP on tablet it throws UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path "/dev" is denied.

How can I grant access to this directory without rooting tablet ? I dont think I need because i tried other APP from Google Play to read from my serial device and it works great.

Can you help me with this ? I hope for some "grant permission in manifest xml" tip or something. I searched a lot but nothing fits my case...

Comment: Making changes on the `/dev` folder could break the whole system. Is it really necessary? Better rethink your structure...

Comment: Read again. :) I just need to read output of serial device... no changes :)

Comment: Have you granted the `android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in your manifest file?

Comment: I read about this but I didnt think it would help me cos i dont need anything from external storage right ? But for sake of argument i tried it just now and no change at all :/

Comment: Curious if you ever solved this. Facing the same issue.